# Google Sheets with Google App Script: How to write a 'status' message to the cell before returning the final result?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a function that can take a while to return the output.  Is there a way to have it print a message in the cell, before overwriting the message with the output a short time later?  The function can take 30 seconds to run and it may be used in 20-30 cells, hence it would be nice to see which cell is still calculating and which is done.

```js
function do_calc() {
  print("Now doing the calculations...")
    
  // ... (bunch of code here that does the calculations)
    
  return output;
}
```

I tried to use `setvalue()` but it says I don't have permission to do that in a custom function:

[image: You do not have permission to call setValue]

Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(), 10).setValue('Running...');
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  return 'Finished';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues:

Like I said in the comment you can't `return` twice because the first `return` statement will cancel out the code that comes after that.

- Also set methods (like `setValue`) are not allowed in custom function as clearly stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

### Solution:

The solution would be to incorporate the built in google sheets formula [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en).

```
=iferror(myFunction(),"Running...")
```

where `myFunction` is:

```
function myFunction() {
  try{
    // some code that delays
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
  catch(e){
    return e.message;
  } 
  return 'Finished';
}
```

I added a [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to make sure you `return` the error messages that are related to the script. Otherwise, `iferror` will hide them.

[image]

**Be careful!**

A custom function call must return within **30 seconds**. If this time is surpassed then the custom function will return the error:

> Exceeded maximum execution time

which will not be shown because you have used `iferror` which will cover the error.

Comment: i ticked it, It works, but I just don't know why it works.  It says IFERROR would only execute if the function returns an error, but there's no error.

Comment: @chiwal when the function is calculating stuff then in the sheet it returns some temporary error this is why we use `iferror` to catch it.